# clerical work VS. office work

Tags: vocabulary

It would be greatly appreciated if somebody throw a light on whether or not there is any difference between these?

clerical work

office work

secretarial work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Secretarial work' specifically refers to the job of a secretary, which typically includes answering phones and email and interfacing with the public.

'Clerical work' typically indicates a class of work done by a clerk or secretary, including answering phones, data entry, responding to email, but also filing, preparing reports, and so on.

'Office work' can include clerical or secretarial work but it can also mean any general work in an office context.